# How to repeat n values in list m times in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list

For example, I have a list

```cs
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

and I want to repeat its content 3 times to get in result

```cs
{ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 }
```

Is there a simpler solution than just `AddRange` m times in for loop?

Comment: How do you define "better" in this context?

Comment: I mean, you could use Linq and `Concat` or `Repeat`- whether that's "better" or not is up for debate. There's not a lot of language-level array creation shortcuts like some other languages have.

Comment: If you want to add to the existing list, I can't think of anything. If you wanted to create a new list then you could use a LINQ one-liner but, given how simple the solution you're already talking about would be, is it really worth it? It's taken you far longer to post here than implement the solution you're trying to simplify.

Comment: @user18387401 I'm just asking for alternatives out of curiosity

Comment: A more interesting question might be the fastest solution, and that's likely to be pre-allocating the array and using `Array.Copy` in a loop

Comment: *"I'm just asking for alternatives out of curiosity"*. That's not what this site is for. That question may be fine on forums or elsewhere on Stack Exchange but SO is for specific problems and you don't have one.

Comment: @user18387401 why my question may not be considered as a specific problem? Maybe I can't use for some reason the solution I have. I've seen many similar by concept questions on SO.

Comment: *"Maybe I can't use for some reason the solution I have"*. Maybe you're just making that up because you know your question isn't appropriate for SO. *"I've seen many similar by concept questions on SO"*. That other people have posted bad questions doesn't make yours any better. You've got code that works, therefore you don't have a problem, therefore you don't have a question for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `Enumerable.Repeat`

```
var repeatCount = 3; //change this value to repeat n times
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = Enumerable.Repeat(list, repeatCount).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's `Enumerable.Range` with `SelectMany`:

```
list = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
   .SelectMany(_ => list)
   .ToList();
```

Or similar approach with `Repeat`:

```
list = Enumerable.Repeat(list, 3)
   .SelectMany(_ => list)
   .ToList();
```

Note that both will differ from adding to the list - a new list is created and assigned to `list` variable.